# Getting exception syntax error

Tags: python

I wrote a function. Now I keep getting syntax errors within the try statement. I don't know if its the code I wrote or the try statement

Function:

```
   def connector (links):
      for links in infile:                    
      avenues = links.rstrip()               
      words = []                          
      dct = {}
      cord = []
```

There is more to the code but the error keeps occurring in the try statement, where it says except, any ideas?

```
try:
  infile = open("routes.txt", "r")
  links = inf.readlines()
  Connector(links)
  except LookupError as exceptObj:
      print("Error:", str(exceptObj))
```

Comment: `connector` is lowercase

Answer (score 1):

- `connector` should be lowercase
- You indented wrong

  ```
  try:
    infile = open("routes.txt", "r")
    links = inf.readlines()
    connector(links)
  except LookupError as exceptObj:
    print("Error:", str(exceptObj))
  ```